# RegEx: Find & Replace snake_case to UpperCamelCase/PascalCase Between Characters

Tags: regex, replace, ide, text-editor

I am using my IDE's Find & Replace (w/ RegEx) feature to find & replace the type parameter of arguments to go from snake_case to PascalCase (AKA UpperCamelCase). There are several files and lines throughout the project that need to be changed, and manually doing so is quite error prone and tedious (plus I am sure I am going to need the essential pattern again for future changes).

For example:

```
CURRENT: function find_all_by_name_and_status(_i_find_all_by_name_and_statusCriteria find_all_by_name_and_status_criteria) ...
```

Should be:

```
DESIRED: function find_all_by_name_and_status(IFindAllByNameAndStatusCriteria find_all_by_name_and_status_criteria) ...
```

The patterns I am using are the following:

```
FIND: (?<=\()_(.)(Criteria)*

REPLACE: \U$1\L
```

The replace pattern will work, as far as I can see, if the 1st found capture group is correct (the letter just after an "_").

The core pattern of `_(.)` finds the correct components to replace, however, it captures the other parts of the string as well. So, I added a positive lookbehind `(?<=\()` to start at the opening parentheses and an ending dummy capture for `(Criteria)*`. The entire pattern seems to cause the core pattern to only match once and not repeatedly. `(?R)` does not seem to help either.

P.S.

It looks the `(Criteria)*` does not do anything either, but I figured that is the second problem to address after getting the core pattern to find all matches / repeat.

I feel like I am close to a solution, but not quite there yet. I, of course, could be VERY off base on the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression,

```
(.*\()|(_)([a-z])([a-z]*)|(Criteria.*)
```

which is not really the best one, with a replacement of something similar to:

```
$1\U$3\L$4\E$5
```

might likely work here (the `\E` is for demoing).

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QZlhIY/1/) on the right panel, the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This indeed worked, though I believe as you noted: it is not "highly" performant if the target document(s) / string(s) are _very_ large. For my purposes, about 2k+ lines, it worked fine. I am accepting this as the answer since it is testable on regex101.com as well (just in case future users need something similar) though Toto's answer was very good too. It might be useful to add a small explanation of what some of the parts do, for future readers / searchers. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is working with Notepad++

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\(|\G)_(.[^\W_]*)(?=\w+Criteria)`
- Replace with: `$1\u$2`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\(|\G)             # group 1, openning parenthesis or restart from last match position
_                   # underscore
(.[^\W_]*)          # group 2, 1 any character followed by 0 or more alphanum
(?=\w+Criteria)     # positive lookahead, make sure we have 1 or more word character and Criteria
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
\u$2        # content of group 2 with first character uppercased
```

**Result for given example:**

```
function find_all_by_name_and_status(IFindAllByNameAndStatusCriteria find_all_by_name_and_status_criteria) ...
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer and a very thorough explanation! However, I should have noted that I am on a Mac / UNIX system so I don't have access to Notepad++ (sadly) so perhaps that is why this answer did not work for me (even on regex101.com). I believe it is because of the "Wrap around" restriction required". However, this is still a good answer and probably correct (I plan to test it out at some point on my Windows machine and report back).